# ReactJS require inside if else condition not work properly after build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement

Here is my code:

```
var selectedTheme = "dark";

if (selectedTheme == "dark") {
  require('./styleDark.css');
  alert('Dark Selected')
} else {
  require('./styleLight.css');
  alert('Light Selected')
}
```

When I was testing it by `npm start`, it was work perfectly. But when I build the project by `yarn build` and deploy it online, that's wasn't work perfectly.

When the dark mode selected, its alert  `alert('Dark Selected')` but the `require('./styleLight.css');` was also working. Why the `require('./styleLight.css');` is working while its alert `alert('Dark Selected')`?

Comment: What build tool do you use?

Comment: @DamianDziaduch the OP has mentioned yarn

Comment: @S.Alvi, yarn is not a build tool, it is a package manager

Comment: @DamianDziaduch pretty sure yarn has an in-built command called `yarn build` that does the same job as any build tool. It builds static files for production use. Unless I misunderstood what you are asking I think I am right

Comment: @S.Alvi yarn build only runs the script defined in the package.json https://yarnpkg.com/cli/run but it does not do the actual build